# React - Link in URL is #[object%20HTMLParagraphElement] instead of #id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that calculates the right position for my fixed tabs to scroll to, but i've noticed when they scroll to this position it changes the URL to #[object%20HTMLParagraphElement] instead of #idname.

The below is my function and is triggered onClick when a user clicks one of the tabs on my fixed navigation

```
calculateScrollPosition (e) {
  const nav = document.querySelector('#navbar')
  if (!nav) return

  let navHeight = nav.getBoundingClientRect().height
  let section = document.querySelector(e.target.parentElement.dataset.link)
  let sectionTop = section.getBoundingClientRect().top

  const body = document.body
  const docEl = document.documentElement

  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop
  const clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0
  const top = Math.round(sectionTop + scrollTop - clientTop)

  let scrollHeight = top - navHeight
  window.scroll(0, scrollHeight)
  window.location.hash = e.target
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> window.location.hash = e.target
> ```

You're assigning the target element to it instead of the id of the target element.

```
window.location.hash = e.target.id
```

Or some other feature of the target element that we know nothing about because you didn't include any HTML in your example code.